# What's the difference between blocks and methods in Java?

Tags: java, methods, block

I'm learning Java and I can't understand the difference between a block and a method.

Comment: When you say block, do you mean the contents of two curly braces Like `{ /* stuff here */}`?

Comment: Java Language Specification [14.2. Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) and [8.4. Method Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) (at least the very first line of each)

Comment: You can also create a block just to limit the lifetime of a variable, has more usage in C/C++ though.

Answer (score 3):

Block is a series of statements enclosed in curly braces.

Uses of blocks include, but not limited to:

- Methods (A block is required since it is the method's body)
- If/Else statements
- For/While/Do-While Loops
- Lambdas

A method is a block in the class scope that might accept a set of parameters and might produce a result through the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Code blocks GENERALLY live inside methods (but not always, there are exceptions).

Methods are also (generally) named and can be called from elsewhere in your code by that name. Blocks cannot, they can only be reached by following the flow of the code in your class (so generally through calling the method they're contained in and reaching the proper conditions for their execution).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above answers there is one more block, that is static block like the below one.

```
public class Block {
    static {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: that is a [Static Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) and there is also an [Instance Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6)